# How to navigate to and enter input in nested frame/form with mechanize

Tags: python, iframe, screen-scraping, mechanize

I want to enter some text (login, password) inside a page with frames. The structure is something like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>Whatever</head>
      <body id="Body">
            <form id="frmM" onsubmit="javascript:return whatever();" action="Login.aspx" method="post">
                  <div id="alldata">
                        <div id="header">
                              <iframe id="Login_SSL" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" src="https://www.whatever.com/User/LoginFrame.aspx?redir=/User/Login.aspx">
                                    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                          <body onload="refreshParent()">
                                                <form id="form1" action="LoginFrame.aspx?redir=%2fUser%2fLogin.aspx" method="post">
                                                      <div id="loginRow" class="loginMenuRow" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'cmdLogin')">
                                                            <input id="cmdLogin" type="submit" tabindex="3" onclick="aspnetForm.target ='_top';" value="Login" name="cmdLogin">
                                                             <input id="Password" class="textbox" type="password" tabindex="2" name="Password">
                                                             <span id="lblPassword" class="loginMenu">Password:</span>
                                                       </div>
                                                </form>
                                            </body>
                                      </html>
                              </iframe>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

If I try to find the form, I see that only the top level one is available.

```
>>br.select_form("form1")
FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'form1'
>>[f.attrs['id'] for f in br.forms()]
['frmM']
```

How do I go about logging in to this site?

Comment: couldn't you just open "https://www.whatever.com/User/LoginFrame.aspx?redir=/User/Login.aspx"?

Comment: @utdemir, I'd love to, but I am not so good with HTTP, how do I enter the password in the this URL?

Answer (score 4):

2 options:

- Access the URL within the iframe directly and then do your form login
- Login to the site from your browser and use an extension like Firebug
  to track the posted data. Then replicate this request to login
  automatically.